# How to draw 2d road similiar to Outrun, Lotus, Pitstop, Cisco Heat games?

Tags: 2d, libgdx, racing, curves

*** UPDATED 23/05/2018 ***

I've managed to implement road generation and curves using the techniques described [here](https://github.com/OneLoneCoder/videos/blob/master/OneLoneCoder_RetroArcadeRacer.cpp)

I made a [short gameplay video](https://youtu.be/7VYmq992qKo).

[image]

Hope it helps to anybody looking for answers.

Comment: I've been without time recently. Today I hope I can update. Basically, I have to draw the road pixel by pixel. I don't know how to take a road texture and bend to make curves. I'm totally lost. Can't figure it out.

Comment: Question updated. Discarded textures for now. Im trying to understand and achieve a more natural curve effect.

Comment: Thanks for updating your question. Can you include in the body of the question itself a description of the specific steps from the linked resources you're trying to replicate, and where you're running into trouble? Right now a user trying to catch up on where you're at has to cross-reference several different pages, making it harder to figure out what kind of help you need (and this can also make the question less useful for future users after the links rot away). The more self-contained you can make your question, typically, the faster it attracts answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've managed to generate roads and curves using the techniques described in the links provided above, or you can watch the video [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KkMZI5Jbf18).

I cannot explain it better than that, so anyone wondering how to do it, please check it out.